# Is there a Python equivalent to Matlab's makelut, applylut?

Tags: python, image-processing, lookup-tables, binary-image

I am working with some image processing routines, using binary images.  In Matlab I can create a lookup table which provides the output for every possible 2^9=512 configurations of 3 x 3 neighbourhoods.  That is, I can write a function `func` which produces a 0 or 1 for such a neighbourhood, and then create a lookup table with

```
lut = makelut(func,3)
```

(the "3" indicating the size of neighbourhood).  Then that lookup table can be applied to my binary image `im` with

```
applylut(im, lut)
```

But how can I do the same thing in Python?  There is an example given here:

http://pydoc.net/Python/scikits-image/0.4.2/skimage.morphology.skeletonize/

which certainly works, but seems very complicated, at least compared to Matlab's commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [filters defined in `scipy.ndimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters) may be of use to you. If none of the pre-defined filters match your intent, you can apply a custom filter using
[`scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter).

For example, you can reproduce the result shown on the [Mathworks applylut doc page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/applylut.html) with:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
from PIL import Image

filename = '/tmp/PerformErosionUsingA2by2NeighborhoodExample_01.png'
img = Image.open(filename).convert('L')
arr = np.array(img)
def func(x):
    return (x==255).all()*255
arr2 = ndimage.generic_filter(arr, func, size=(2,2))
new_img = Image.fromarray(arr2.astype('uint8'), 'L')
new_img.save('/tmp/out.png')
```

[PerformErosionUsingA2by2NeighborhoodExample_01.png](http://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/images/PerformErosionUsingA2by2NeighborhoodExample_01.png):

[image]

out.png:

[image]

Note that in this case, [`ndimage.grey_erosion`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_erosion.html) can produce the same result, and
since it is not calling a Python function once for every pixel, it's also a lot
faster:

```
arr3 = ndimage.grey_erosion(arr, size=(2,2))
print(np.allclose(arr2,arr3))
# True
```

---

Depending on the kind of computation you wish to perform in `func`, another faster alternative may be to express the result as a NumPy computation on slices. For example, the above `grey_erosion` could also be expressed as

```
arr4 = np.pad(arr.astype(bool), ((1,0),(1,0)), 'reflect')
arr4 = arr4[:-1,:-1] & arr4[1:,:-1] & arr4[:-1,1:] & arr4[1:,1:]
arr4 = arr4.astype('uint8')*255
assert np.allclose(arr3, arr4)
```

Again this is much faster than using `generic_filter` since here the computation is being performed on whole arrays rather than pixel-by-pixel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your long and detailed reply!  in fact I did realize not long after sending my query that `ndimage.generic_filter` would do the job.  It's a bit slow though - not unlike Matlab's `nlfilter` - whereas `applylut` seems highly optimized.  For what it's worth I'm using scikit-image in preference to PIL.  Thank you again!